# Dict key as function in a class

Tags: python

How do I call the get_productname function from the dictionary in the code below?

```
test = {
       'get_productname' : {
                         'id' : 1,
                         'active' : 1,
                         }
    }

class search(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in test.items():
            if test[key]['active']:
                ... here i want to call the "get_productname" function from the dict key name
                self.key()
                ... HOW CAN I DO THIS?

    def get_productname(self, id):
        ...
        return productname
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `getattr` function.

```
class search(object):
  def __init__(self):
    for key, value in test.items():
      if test[key]['active']:
        getattr(self, key)(test['key']['id'])
```

Per the comments, if you're not 100% positive that the method will exist you can perform a `hasattr(self, name)` check ahead of time, but it's equivalent to this:

```
try:
  getattr(self, key)
except AttributeError, e:
  # code here that would handle a missing method.
```

Comment: The best way to ensure that the method exists is to try `getattr` and catch the `AttributeError` -- that's what `hasattr` does!

Comment: You can also just `getattr(self, key, None)` (replace `None` with whatever default value you want to get if the function doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3):

If you know in advance what classes the methods you want to call belong to, you could use the methods itself instead of their names as dictionary keys.  Then you can simply call them:

```
class search(object):
    def __init__(self, test):
        for func, value in test.iteritems():
            if value['active']:
                func(self, value['id'])
    def get_productname(self, id):
        pass

test = {search.get_productname: {'id' : 1, 'active' : 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `get_productname()` function defined somewhere, I'd just add it to the dictionary like this:

```
test = {
       'get_productname' : {
                         'id' : 1,
                         'active' : 1,
                         'func' : get_productname
                         }
    }
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
class search(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in test.items():
            if test[key]['active']:
                # then call the associated function like this
                test[key]['func']()
                ...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even though people might flame me for suggesting this:

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval

Try this:

```
test = {
       'get_productname' : {
                         'id' : 1,
                         'active' : 1,
                         }
    }

class search(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in test.items():
            if test[key]['active']:
                eval("self.%s()" % key)
                # or, if you want to pass ID as an arg:
                eval("self.%(method_name)s(id=%(id)s)" % \
                      dict(method_name=key, id=value["id"])

    def get_productname(self, id):
        ...
        return productname
```

Haven't run it, but that should work.

Comment: hmmm, nevermind. The getattr suggestion above seems to be a much better usage in this case. Avoid eval whenever possible of course, std disclaimer.